# LUIS: Edit project downloaded from Azure

Tags: user-interface, azure-devops, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have subscription on Azure and I dowloaded chat bot with my AppId and password. On page luis.ai I trained new model and exported it to downloaded azure project (with flight booking). I replaced their cognitive model with my model from luis.ai, but after that - azure project is always working with old data. I don´t understand why, because their model is removed from my PC. What should I do to working with my own model? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear? It sounds like you created a bot on Azure, and you downloaded the bot files to run it locally? And then you created a new LUIS model, exported the application, and replaced some local LUIS file with the new one? And then it's still recognizing the flight booking model even though it's not there? I'm not terribly familiar with accessing local LUIS models. Can you add your code where you are calling the LUIS model and some additional details on what the expected and actual behavior is (with specifics)?

Comment: Sorry, but yes, you understood my problem. Project created on Microsoft Azure I downloaded to my PC and started this project. Then I went to page luis.ai and I trained new model with my own intents and utterances .. I exported it and used to my project saved locally. But no effect

Comment: Can you share the part of your code where you call the LUIS model? I think that will be a good first step to understanding why you are not getting the expected results.

Comment: https://ctrlv.sk/shots/2020/04/22/qCP4.png

Comment: Can you also show where you define the luisRecognizer (e.g. `const luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({...`)? I'm not familiar with calling a local LUIS model, but I might be able to figure it out if I can understand what your code is doing currently.

Comment: Of course.

https://ctrlv.sk/shots/2020/04/22/IFlL.png

and here is contain of botbuilder-ai..

https://ctrlv.sk/shots/2020/04/22/ywDS.png

I change model like this:

https://ctrlv.sk/shots/2020/04/22/teP4.png

But my local LUIS is not effected with changes in this model JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212285/discussion-between-lukas-and-billoverton).

Answer (score 1):

You code is based on the core-bot sample. First of all, make sure that your LUIS configuration is set up correctly in your .env file (or in App Settings if running from Azure). The recognizer is created in index.js and passed to MainDialog.js. From the core-bot sample code, I'm actually not seeing where it is importing the local code. I think that is maybe just to give you the model to import to your own LUIS app? If you have the proper LUIS keys and app ID, it should respond to whatever you have in there. My guess is maybe that you replaced the FlightBooking.json LUIS model file, but didn't actually point the bot to your LUIS app with the new intents.

I would suggest, though, that this isn't the best sample to use if you are trying to just tweak it. There are a lot of things here that are set up specifically for booking flights that don't really make sense if that's not what your bot is doing. Personally I like the [Dispatch Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch) sample better as a starting point (even if you are not using Dispatch CLI tool), though it has the intent actions within the bot file instead of separate dialogs. Maybe that will give you a better starting point though?